# Not able to publish flow to Node-RED via the HTTP API, but it works when doing it manually

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am trying to use the Node-RED API to publish a flow with this command:

```
curl -ss -X POST \
      http://${IP_ADDRESS}:1880/flow \
      -H 'content-type: application/json' \
      --data-binary "@foo_nodered_flow.json"
```

(as per API docs here: https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/flow/)

but I get back this message:

```
{"error":"unexpected_error","message":"Error: duplicate id"}
```

The flow is more or less:

- an MQTT subscriber
- a function to transform messages in Javascript
- a connection to InfluxDB to store these transformed messages (for this I have installed a custom npm package `node-red-contrib-influxdb` inside `~/.node-red/` https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-influxdb)

I don't find duplicate IDs in the field `id` when grepping with `grep -nrI id foo_nodered_flow.json`.

I was able to publish via HTTP POST a similar flow that was not involving InfluxDB but a simple file writer.

- Why I am getting that error in the HTTP response? What's wrong with that flow?
- How can I programmatically publish any flow using `curl`?

The file containing the flow has this structure:

```
{
  "label": "Store redings - panel flow",
  "nodes": [ <put here the flow you export from the Node-RED UI> ],
  "configs": []
}
```

Make sure that the list of `nodes` is being cleaned from the node of type `"type": "tab"` containing the name of the flow e.g. `"label": "Flow 1"` (this label must go outside the `nodes` array as the first field as in the above sample).

**I also tried to remove the top level `id` field and all the `z` fields which seem to be automatically replaced/fixed. But I still get the same errors.**

I know this flow works because when I manually created it, then I was able to see the data flowing and being eventually stored inside InfluxDB.

Also when on the Node-RED UI (at `http://${THE_IP_ADDRESS}:1880/`) I can click on the "3 lines menu" > Import > Clipboard then paste the JSON description of the nodes of that flow and I am able to import the flow with no errors and then deploy the flow with no errors.

I am using:

- node version: 10.14.2
- Node-RED version: 0.19.5
- node-red-contrib-influxdb version: 0.2.2

Comment: Make sure that there is no duplicate keys/ids in your JSON file.

Comment: I don't find duplicate IDs in the field `id` when grepping with `grep -nrI id foo_nodered_flow.json`

Comment: @TPPZ were you able to solve this? same exception with NR2, doesnt say which id is duplicate

Comment: I think I did it - but dont have the code on hand I am afraid, if I find it I will post, but I doubt this is going to be anytime soon